# Azure Service Bus UnauthorizedError: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature inside Kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm getting an error:

> UnauthorizedError: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature

when I'm trying to access Azure Service Bus from a nodejs docker container running inside Kubernetes cluster in Azure.

Interesting to note that I don't get this error when I run the code locally, or just inside the docker container on my dev laptop but as soon as I deploy container to K8 cluster I'm getting that error.

I verified the service-bus SAS primary key is correct inside K8 cluster secrets file.

Here's how error object looks like inside K8 cluster:

```
UnauthorizedError: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature. {"timestamp":"2019-01-08T05:43:48.918Z"}
debug: condition: com.microsoft:auth-failed {"timestamp":"2019-01-08T05:43:48.920Z"}
debug: info: undefined {"timestamp":"2019-01-08T05:43:48.920Z"}
debug: message: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature. {"timestamp":"2019-01-08T05:43:48.924Z"}
debug: name: UnauthorizedError {"timestamp":"2019-01-08T05:43:48.924Z"}
debug: retryable: false {"timestamp":"2019-01-08T05:43:48.924Z"}
debug: stack: UnauthorizedError: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature.
    at Object.translate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@azure/amqp-common/dist/lib/errors.js:527:17)
    at Receiver.messageCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@azure/amqp-common/dist/lib/requestResponseLink.js:109:44)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emit (/usr/src/app/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/util/utils.js:129:24)
    at Object.emitEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/util/utils.js:140:9)
    at Receiver._link.on (/usr/src/app/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/link.js:249:25)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Receiver.link.dispatch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/rhea/lib/link.js:59:37)
    at Incoming.on_transfer (/usr/src/app/node_modules/rhea/lib/session.js:360:22)
    at Session.on_transfer (/usr/src/app/node_modules/rhea/lib/session.js:736:19) {"timestamp":"2019-01-08T05:43:48.925Z"}
debug: translated: true {"timestamp":"2019-01-08T05:43:48.925Z"}
```

I'm using [@azure/service-bus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-node) as a node package to work with azure service bus.

Any help, suggestions or ideas highly appreciated.

Thank you very one.

Comment: well, the issue is definitely in how you pass the key to the container. how do you do that? can you just hardcode the key into the container and see if it works?

Comment: That is good idea. So I tried to hardcode the connection string and I'm getting the same error inside K8 cluster. It works as charm if I run this code locally or just inside docker image on my laptop.
My code looks like this [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-node/blob/master/examples/topics/receiveComplete.ts) I passed SAS primary hardcoded connection string into `createFromConnectionString` method call and deployed image into K8 cluster waited for a pod to spin up, looked at the logs same error.

Comment: hm, how did you create k8s cluster? can it be that time it badly out of sync on the nodes?

Comment: You know what, I redeployed container one more time just to be sure, and **you were right in your first comment**, the hardcoded SAS string worked.

But, I why it doesn't take it from K8 secrets file correctly I'm wondering.

Comment: just pass it as env variable:https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables

Comment: Yeah, that is what I'm doing [secrets](https://imgur.com/a/4ORDQg6). Do you think it could be the reason that I have the name `AZURE_SERVICEBUS_CONNECTION_STRING` in both places as `name` and `key` in my manifest yml file ?

Comment: no, I'm doing that all the time, that shouldnt matter. just examine your environment variable, maybe some character is missing? when you created the secret it was interpreted as an escape character or something like that? I bet the SAS secret is 1 character shorter than the hardcoded one

Comment: @DmitryLukianenko I had this happen when I've accidentally appended the end-of-line character to the base64 representation of the connection string in the secrets file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case the issue was with the way OP passes the SAS string to the container